# Sitecore Forms email field validation message is showing in English instead of Korean language

Tags: sitecore-forms

I created a Sitecore Form in Korean language (ko-Kr) version.

For an Email field on this form, we used Email Validator and updated the error message on this path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Validations/Email Validator` to Korean language.

Now if I type "" or if i enter an invalid email id, it is showing the validation error message in English language.

Whereas if I type "sd@s", I am getting error message which I configured for the validation item path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Validations/Email Validator`

[image]

If I type Alphanumeric character, it is showing error message in English.

Can someone suggest why I am getting the error message in English in this scenario?

[image]

Comment: I have done few major edits to your question. Please have a look to make sure the edits are not changing the context of your problem.

Comment: Is there any option to fix this issue?

Comment: What kind of validations do you have set for this field? Take a look here -> https://imgur.com/IxAkCLK

Comment: I think the only reliable answer to this will be from Sitecore Support. You should raise a ticket.

Comment: @PeterProcházka - using Email validator for validation

Comment: The other solution i tried is - instead of having Email field item with Email validator i have used normal single line text field with email validator in valadation multilist selection and the validation is working as expected without any english messages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known issue in Forms as it uses the default jQuery validation and there are no any localized scripts on custom language translations ootb. The issue is seen on the email validator - as long as jquery thinks it is a bad email, you will see the English text. After that you can see the translated text (the regex from Sitecore is different from the jquery one). There is a "wish" report to add support for the ootb languages and at least add documentation on how to fix this for other languages: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/482062

I was told (by Support - thx to them) this should do it:

1. Download [jquery-validation source](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation) and extract the zip file
2. Copy the `jquery-validation-master\src\localization` folder to the `\sitecore modules\Web\ExperienceForms\scripts` folder.
3. Include the following script below the `@RenderBody()` helper in the `\Views\Shared\MVCOuterLayout.cshtml` file:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var lang = '@Sitecore.Context.Language.Name';
   var script = document.createElement("script");
   if (lang == 'ko-KR')
   {
       script.src = "/sitecore%20modules/Web/ExperienceForms/scripts/localization/messages_ko.js";
       $("head").append(script);
   }
   </script>
   ```
4. Find the error message in the `\sitecore modules\Web\ExperienceForms\scripts\localization\messages_ko.js` file and translate as desired. Should be something with `email: "..."`

You can also create a `messages_<languageCode>.js` file in the `\sitecore modules\Web\ExperienceForms\scripts\localization` folder and modify the script logic to handle other language translation.

Edit: Just verified this and it does seem to work fine.

If you need to do this in a SXA environment: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2019/04/sitecore-9-forms-translating-client-error.html

Answer (score 3):

@Gatogordo - Thanks for sharing.

The easiest way we can fix this issue.

Step 1: Copy the "messages_ko.js"  file and paste the to the `\sitecore modules\Web\ExperienceForms\scripts` folder.

Step 2: Give the "messages_ko.js" file name to the script field in Sitecore form and publish the item.
Ex: [image]

Now it's reflecting the Korean language for email validation.

this is the custom message
[image]

Custom message:

[image]

Comment: Glad to be of assistance ;)  Didn't test it in the scripts field yet as that is shared. Curious how that behaves in a multi-lingual environment..

Comment: We tested in multi-lingual environment. it will cause the translate content issue. correct solution -- we need to update script either sitecore form wrapper or layout.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative solution, avoiding hardcoding the texts for other languages in javascript files:

Edit the file `Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates\Email.cshtml` and remove `type="email"`
With this change, jQuery's validation doesn´t kick in, and you only get the regex validation of the email field, with its managed error message, avoiding the message "**please enter a valid email address**".

I would do the same on the view `EmailConfirmation.cshtml`